# OneToMany insert causing an detached entity passed to persist error

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, reactive, quarkus-panache

Im trying to persist data using hibernate-panache to a `OneToMany` tables Feature and FeatureRole. Created a service method that Input will be `List<Long>` ids of features and `String` role name. I want to insert FeatureRole table with each features (from ids) and role name.

```
return Panache.withTransaction(() -> {
            return featuresRepository.findByIds(ids).collect().asList().onItem().transform(t -> {
                FeatureRole fr = new FeatureRole();
                fr.setRole_name("role name");
                for (Features fe: t) {
                    fr.setFeatures(fe);
                    fe.getFeatureRoles().add(fr);
                }
                return featureRoleRepository.persistAndFlush(fr).map(to -> fr);
            }).flatMap(t -> t);
        });
```

When I run this an error occured. Saying that the feature insert to feature_role table is not persisted. How can we solve this error.

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: io.github.jithset.models.Features
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyNow(CompletableFuture.java:670)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:658)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApply(CompletableFuture.java:2094)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApply(CompletableFuture.java:143)
                at org.hibernate.reactive.util.impl.CompletionStages.lambda$loop$5(CompletionStages.java:170)
                at com.ibm.asyncutil.iteration.AsyncTrampoline.lambda$asyncWhile$1(AsyncTrampoline.java:209)
                at com.ibm.asyncutil.iteration.AsyncTrampoline$TrampolineInternal.unroll(AsyncTrampoline.java:119)
                at com.ibm.asyncutil.iteration.AsyncTrampoline$TrampolineInternal.trampoline(AsyncTrampoline.java:101)
                at com.ibm.asyncutil.iteration.AsyncTrampoline$TrampolineInternal.access$200(AsyncTrampoline.java:84)
                at com.ibm.asyncutil.iteration.AsyncTrampoline.asyncWhile(AsyncTrampoline.java:192)
                at com.ibm.asyncutil.iteration.AsyncTrampoline.asyncWhile(AsyncTrampoline.java:209)
                at org.hibernate.reactive.util.impl.CompletionStages.loop(CompletionStages.java:169)
                at org.hibernate.reactive.util.impl.CompletionStages.loop(CompletionStages.java:186)
                at org.hibernate.reactive.session.impl.ReactiveSessionImpl.fire(ReactiveSessionImpl.java:1076)
                at org.hibernate.reactive.session.impl.ReactiveSessionImpl.firePersist(ReactiveSessionImpl.java:696)
                ... 67 more
```

> Feature Role

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "feature_role")
public class FeatureRole {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "featureRoleSeq", sequenceName = "featureRoleSeq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "featureRoleSeq")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "features_id", nullable = false)
    @Getter @Setter
    @JsonbTransient
    private Features features;

    @Getter @Setter
    private String role_name;

}
```

> Features

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "features")
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Features {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "featureSequence", sequenceName = "featureSequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "featureSequence")
    @Column(name = "feature_id")
    @Getter @Setter
    public Long id;

    @Getter @Setter
    @NotBlank
    @Column(unique = true)
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "features",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @Getter @Setter
    private List<FeatureRole> featureRoles =new ArrayList<>();

    public Features(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Features from(Row row) {
        return new Features(row.getLong("feature_id"), row.getString("name"));
    }`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your mapping, a `FeatureRole` can be associated to a single `Features` (many-to-one). In your code, you are looping over several `Features` and rewriting the association every time you call
`fr.setFeatures(fe);`.

This means that only the last `Features` in the loop will have the correct association because `fr` is only associated to a single element.

Assuming that a `Features` can have many `FeatureRole`, you need to decide which use case applies:

**1. A `FeatureRole` can have many `Features`**

Then it's a [bidirectional many-to-many association](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional) and you have to rewrite your mapping to something similar to:

```
...
class FeatureRole {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Features> features;
    ...
    public void addFeature(Features features) {
     this.features.add( features );
     features.getFeatureRoles().add( this );
 }
```

```
...
class Features {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(mappedby="features")
    private List<FeatureRole> featureRoles =new ArrayList<>()
    ...
}
```

and then the code in the loop becomes:

```
for (Features fe: t) {
    fr.addFeatures(fe);
}
```

**2. A single `FeatureRole` can only be associated to one `Features`**

Then something need to change in the logic of the loop.
But I need more details to help you in that case.